# When to expect normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I was wondering when a normal distribution can be expected. I know that things like:

1. heights of people
2. size of things produced by machines
3. errors in measurements
4. blood pressure
5. marks on a test 

    
                      (source: [Math is Fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html))

follow a normal distribution. But would for example the chosen nicknames of people also fall in that category? And if so or if not, why would that be?

Comment: Assumption of normality is common among people who don't know any other distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, what other distributions should we take into consideration?

Comment: The gamma family is useful. There are many others, quite field-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the accumulation of a large number of very small independent contributions will be approximately normal (according to the Central Limit Theorem).  For example, take heights of people: if you're talking about a homogeneous population, all adults of the same gender, so that the height differences are the result only of small environmental and genetic differences, the normal distribution
might be a good approximation.  But if you have males and females, that's
a single factor that makes a significant difference (typically around 13 cm),
and the deviation from normal distribution will be noticeable.  It would be
even more noticeable if you had a population consisting of Dutch men and Indonesian women.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the length (between 0 and 50 characters) of account names a large group of people chooses. Are these a large number of very small independent contributions? Would that result in a normal distribution?

Comment: I don't know of a reasonable model of that type for choosing account names.